# How can we explain these two pesukim?

Tags: torah-study, tehilim-psalms, heaven, deuteronomy

In [Tehillim 115:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.115.16?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) it is written:

> הַשָּׁמַ֣יִם שָׁ֭מַיִם לַה וְ֝הָאָ֗רֶץ נָתַ֥ן לִבְנֵי־אָדָֽם

Translation: “⁦The heavens belong to the LORD, but the earth He gave over to man.” (Source: Sefaria)

In [Devarim 10:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.10.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0), it says:

> הֵ֚ן לַה אֱלֹהֶ֔יךָ הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וּשְׁמֵ֣י הַשָּׁמָ֑יִם הָאָ֖רֶץ וְכׇל־אֲשֶׁר־בָּֽהּ׃

Translation: “The heavens to their uttermost reaches belong to the LORD your G-d, the earth and all that is on it!” (Source: Sefaria)

Further, in [daf 5 of Sukkah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.5a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says that the first pasuk from Tehillim means that HaShem gave the earth to humans as their domain.

So how do we understand the pasuk from Devarim; are they any commentaries that explain how we can differentiate the two pasukim (among others that say HaShem controls the earth.)

Comment: Rabbi Levi in the gemara asks a very similar question https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.35a.21?lang=bi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Radak on the passuk in Tehillim (the Metzudas Dovid says a similar thought) who seems to understand the passuk as saying that humans can rule on earth so long as they realize that it's really all Hashem.

Here's the text

Radak on Psalms 115:16

> השמים. אף על פי שהוא עשה השמים והארץ ממשלת השמי' לו לבדו ואין לאדם בהם דבר, אבל הארץ נתן ממשלתם לבני אדם וצריך שידעו בני אדם ויכירו כי הוא אדון והם פקידים עליה כאשר ירצה יעביר אותם מהפקידות ויתננו לאחרים כלומר שימית אלו ויוליד אחרים, ומי שיכיר שהוא אדון ויראהו כמו הפקיד, האדון יעמידהו בפקידות וישמרהו הזמן הקצוב לו לפיכך אמר אחריו לא המתים יהללו יה אותם שימית אותם האל יתברך טרם זמן הקצוב ימיתם בעונם שלא הכירוהו בחיים שהוא אדון ולא יראו מפניו, והנה ימותו ולא יהללו יה. כי תאבד נפשם במותם: